# How will network bootstrapping work for headless embedded-SIM IoT devices?

Tags: networking, mobile-data, gsm

Is there something akin to the [Wi-Fi Alliance DPP (Device Provisioning Protocol)](https://www.wi-fi.org/downloads-registered-guest/Device_Provisioning_Protocol_Draft_Technical_Specification_Package_v0_0_23_0.zip/31255) in the world of embedded SIM?<sup>1</sup> If so, it would be really nice to get an outline of how it would work at a high level.

The use case I have in mind is soft/embedded SIM provisioning of off-the-shelf, consumer purchases where ownership of the "thing" needs to be transferred from the reseller to the purchaser at point-of-sale. Presumably we would have to give network access to our purchased item according to our mobile subscription. We might later want to sell or give the item to a third party and re-provision according the the new owner's mobile subscription.

As I write this, I'm aware that this may not even be a target use case for soft-SIM, in which case a follow-up question is: what, if any, standards and technologies are targeting off-the-shelf purchases of IoT devices with mobile network access for the general consumer?

<sup>1</sup><sub>For background, take a look first at [this](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~fms27/papers/1999-StajanoAnd-duckling.pdf) paper if you haven't come across DPP before.</sub>

Comment: Haven't had chance to look through these specs yet, but I guess this is what I'm after: https://www.gsma.com/iot/faq/key-documents

Comment: Are you in a position to be able to answer this yourself yet?